# SoundCloud CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION conflict

Tags: php, soundcloud

I was doing a project for university, and I needed to host my web application to any hosting service. Web application is using SoundCloud API.

Locally it was working just perfect. But after hosting it on one hosting service (which one refused to help me with the problem and suggested to use paid service) I got a PHP warning, which says :

> CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set in /home/u298603610/public_html/Services/Soundcloud.php.

The setting of server say that safe mode is turned off and that `open_basedir="(some value)";`

Comment: How did you came at that conclusion (that those settings are ok)? Have you directly read the php.ini file? Those settings can be programatically changed from code later or set from htaccess file. Put a phpinfo()  in the file you mention above, debug more...

Comment: @BogdanConstantinescu I got those settings from the conversation with hosting service staff member. He sent me table with directives with their local/master values

Comment: Please do the thing I suggested you, see what phpinfo() shows you for those settings.

Comment: @BogdanConstantinescu Yes indeed, I checked it right now and seems like staff member has dis informed me. open_basedir is not "" . But safe mode is off.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `httpd.conf`

```
php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

or if you have PHP >= 5.3.0 put this globally at the beginning of your script

```
ini_set('open_basedir', '');  // this will not work as I see in the documentation that you can only tighten an already set folder to a subfolder
```

You can read more about this directive [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

Comment: "As of PHP 5.3.0 open_basedir can be **tightened** at run-time." Highlighted the keyword. Also IIRC this directive can *not* be set in `.htaccess` files.

Comment: @BogdanConstantinescu I am sorry, but this solution did not work

Comment: PeeHaa has right, sorry for missleading you, in that case you should contact your hosting provider and explain him that you need the open_basedir not to be set. I also updated my answer thanks @PeeHaa

Comment: @BogdanConstantinescu That is what I did on first place. But all I got from provider is requirement to pay money and not willing to do anything. Good point is that my web application API is still working and responding so hope university won't subtract many points for this technical problem.